CiviCrm: Missing "Modified Date" Field in Contact Summary for Individual Contact Type
I am using the Contact Layout Editor extension in CiviCRM to customize the Contact Summary for individual contact types. https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor
I want to display the "Modified Date" field for individual contacts, but I can't find this field in the individual contact type.
Is there a reason why this field isn't showing up in the Contact Summary for individual contact types?

But the "Modified Date" field is available when using the Search Kit (form builder) for individual contacts.

Is there a way to directly add the "Modified Date" field to the Contact Summary for individual contacts, or do I need to use hooks or custom code to achieve this? Any insights or guidance would be appreciated.

I think there is a bit of confusion between Contact Layout Editor and Form Builder:

The Contact Layout Editor: specifically helps change the layout of the screen when viewing a contact.
Form Builder: is a general tool to create forms, display search results, and increasingly it is also replacing old areas of the CiviCRM backend, so that they are easier to customize. However, at the moment, it is not used for the "Contact View" screen.


"I want to display the "Modified Date" field for individual contacts"

Normally, recommend going to Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Contact Layout Editor, and from there, to add the field.
However, it seems like "Modified Date" is not a field that is available in the Contact Layout Editor. It is always displayed in the page footer, and cannot be easily customized. If you wish, you could open a feature request on the Github space of the extension.
An overkill alternative solution would be to use SearchKit to find the modified date of a contact, and then add that SearchKit to the View Contact screen using the Contact Layout Editor.
